# Need help setting up MongoDB for SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am trying to configure mongodb for ssl. I have the two certs within a directory on Ubuntu, but when I try to restart the service with the mongodb.conf set up correctly, the service will not start. If I comment out the lines in the mongodb.conf file that I added, I can then start mongodb. I think the syntax is wrong, and not the certs them self.

```
#SSL options
sslMode = requireSSL
#Enable SSL on normal ports
#sslOnNormalPorts = true
# SSL Key file and password
sslPEMKeyFile = /path/to/cert
sslPEMKeyPassword = password   
sslCAFile = /path/to/cert
```

I get this error when I try to start the server with these lines not commented out

> stop: Unknown instance:
>   mongodb start/running, process 7725

If i try to get into mongo shell i get this(assuming this is because I could not restart the service properly)

> Thu Jul 21 14:32:07.660 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
>   exception: connect failed

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb.conf file is a YAML file so you need to format it as such. Meaning you can't use tabs. Also it does look like the syntax you're using isn't correct.

Try this:

```
net:
   #SSL options
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      # SSL Key file and password
      PEMKeyFile: /path/to/cert
      PEMKeyPassword: password   
      CAFile: /path/to/cert
```

Also, I know it's commented out but just wanted to mention, the sslOnNormal ports option is deprecated. See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.sslOnNormalPorts